# In React hook, no e.target in handleChange with setValue()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks

Since I'm learning how to build React forms with hooks, I went through the 3 quicks posts that culminate with [this one](https://medium.com/@grigorylapshin/and-even-more-forms-ab842a559d4b). Everything is going well until I get to the last step when you create your custom hook with:

```
function useFormInput(initialValue) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  function handleChange(e) {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }

  return {
    value,
    onChange: handleChange
  };
}
```

The Input is:

```
const Input = ({ type, name, onChange, value, ...rest }) => (
    <input
        name={name}
        type={type}
        value={value}
        onChange={event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            onChange(name, event.target.value);
        }}
        {...rest}
    />
);
```

And the Form is:

```
const Form = () => {
  const email = useFormInput("");
  const password = useFormInput("");

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={e =>
        e.preventDefault() || alert(email.value) || alert(password.value)
      }
    >
      <Input 
        name="email" 
        placeholder="e-mail" 
        type="email" 
        {...email} 
      />
      <Input
        name="password"
        placeholder="password"
        type="password"
        {...password}
      />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};
```

So in `useFormInput()` Chrome complains about

> TypeError: Cannot read property ‘value’ of undefined at handleChange

which I'm pretty sure is pointing me to

```
function handleChange(e) {
  setValue(e.target.value);
}
```

If I console.log(e) I get 'email', as expected (I think?), but if I try console.log(e.target) I get undefined. So obviously e.target.value doesn't exist. I can get it working by just using

```
setValue(document.getElementsByName(e)[0].value);
```

but I don't know what kind of issues this might have. Is this a good idea? Are there drawbacks to getting it to work this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue comes from the `onChange` prop in the `Input` component

```
    onChange={event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        onChange(name, event.target.value);
    }}
```

you're calling `onChange` like this `onChange(name, event.target.value);`  (two arguments, the first one is a string), while in your custom hook you define the callback like this

```
  function handleChange(e) {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }
```

it's expecting one argument, an event.

So either call `onChange` with one argument (the event) :

```
onChange={event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    onChange(event);
}}
```

or change the implementation of the callback.

Comment: You're right, that also fixes it, thanks. I thought maybe there was maybe something I could do with that onChange(). So between using the event or using the name in handleChange(), is there some advantage to either or is it basically the same? For example, do I miss out on some functionality by not passing the event around?

Comment: Well, by using the name like you did here `setValue(document.getElementsByName(e)[0].value);`, you have to access the DOM to get the value back, which have some performance implication. So IMO, better use the event or pass the value directly

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
const handleChange = e => {
   const { inputValue } = e.target;
   const newValue = +inputValue;
   setValue(newLimit);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue with a calendar picker library **[react-date-picker](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-date-picker)** using **Register API**. Looking at the documentation found out that there's another way of handling components that don't return the original **event** object on the **onChange** function using the **Controller API**.

More details on [Controller API Docs](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#:%7E:text=React%20Hook%20Form%20embraces%20uncontrolled,controlled%20component%20is%20also%20optimized.)

**Example:**

```
/*
* React Function Component Example
* This works with either useForm & useFormContext hooks.
*/
import { FC } from 'react'
import { Controller, useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form'
import DatePicker,{ DatePickerProps } from 'react-date-picker/dist/entry.nostyle'


const FormDateInput: FC<Omit<DatePickerProps, 'onChange'>> = ({
  name,
  ...props
}) => {
  const formMethods = useFormContext()
  const { control } = formMethods ?? {}

  return (
    <Controller
      render={({ field }) => <DatePicker {...props} {...field} />}
      name={name ?? 'date'}
      control={control}
    />
  )
}

export default FormDateInput
```